# Everything is centered

Tags: html, css

I have this page ([at this URL](http://telpar.altervista.org/AVR/C/timer.html)) that use the following structure.

I have a HEADER.php :

```
<TABLE>
 <TR>
   <TD>Link bar (left)</TD>
   <TD>
```

Then, here I put the contents of the page and include a 
FOOTER.php

```
   </TD>
  </TR>

 <TR>
   <TD>Footer Contents</TD>
 </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Ok, I should use newer DIV, but I am too affectionate to old table methods ;)

The issue: everything is centered (as you can see)! I tried to put align-left everything with no success. The strange thing, is if I remove that contents (and put just "Hello World") everything is fine.

So I think that the HTML/CSS (content) - copy and pasted from a Blogger post - is the source of the issue.

But was wondering how a "corrupted" HTML/CSS (content) can alter previuos entities (Also 'Link bar' is centered!)

The same header.php/footer.php for other pages works fine

Thank you in advance

Comment: The use of bad practices can't be linked to being "old school". I've been working with this since 1999, and this doesn't mean I would layout a page using tables. Anyway... Debug your page using, let's say, Firebug (Firefox) and inspect the CSS being loaded.

Answer (score 2):

"newer DIV", "old table methods"... using tables for your layout is not old, its prehistoric! Please learn how to use div's, you'll see soon enough that it works soooo much easier.

But I also would like to provide an answer, add this to your stylesheet:

```
table tr td { text-align: left; }
```

Comment: I think you should have stop your response to "soooo much easier". Design with table are evil, they have to be banned from the web!

Comment: I didn't want to react to harsh, but I fully agree with you, +1.

Comment: What people don't get is that `table` is intended to make ... well, table, and **nothing else**. Its just a tool, what you do with it is upt o you.

Comment: No! Tables are designed to arrange data. Not to make your layout, therefor we have divs (and ofcourse more elements).

Comment: Now it works with css you suggested. Of course it is a momentary patch. As soon as possible I will rewrite the whole structure by using divs. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your tr{text-align:center;} line 222 AND line 296 of timer.html
You have it twice on both line so remove them all.

You really should put all your CSS on the same place, it would be easier for you to debug.

Comment: I'll rewrite the whole structure ex novo with an unuque css as you suggested me. All the css placed everywhere are the result of so many patches during years: often are useless or overwrite other ones. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

Just define this mentioned below css to achieve your desired result.....

**CSS**

```
table tr td {
text-align:left;
}
```

see the attached demo :- [image]